# A4988 Vref too low

Tags: stepper, a4988

I'm driving a stepper rated at 5V/1.7A using an A4988-based driver circuit with a 12V power supply.  An Arduino controls the stepping sequence.

According to the datasheet for my A4988, I should be calculating Vref as:

Imax = Vref / (8 * Rs)  so,

Vref = I * (8 x Rs) (where Rs is 0.1 ohm on this particular board and confirmed with meter).

So, Vref should be (1.7A x .8) or 1.36V to drive 1.7amps.

The problem is, I cannot adjust the A4988 to get Vref up that high.

With the adjustment pot full swing, the best I can get is .9 to 1V.  When I energize and hold the motor and use an amp meter, the coil is drawing about .9 amps -- which is still less than the 70% of 1.7 Amps I would like (using full-step mode).

Is Vref potential limited by the input voltage of 12 volts?  Is there something else I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Added:  This is the circuit I am using:
[image]

Comment: Can you please provide your circuit diagram/schematic. I suspect your wiring is wrong.

Comment: Image of circuit added..

Comment: I see the circuit but not the adjustment pot referenced in the question, so can't answer yet.

Comment: The adjustment pot is built into the circuit board and came that way.  Rs is also built into the circuit.  http://www.elegoo.com/product/elegoo-stepstick-stepper-motor-driver-module-a4988-heat-sink-for-3d-printer-reprap-cnc-machine-or-roboticspack-of-5/

Answer (score 1):

You have a 30K resistor divider in series with the trimmer. Change the 30K resistor for one rated at 27K to obtain those higher values. ;)